# Div highlight does not translate to div's new position

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I am highlighting a div using `ui-state-highlight` on `mouseover` and also indenting it on mouse `click` event. The div is highlighted perfectly when it is not indented but once it is indented highlight still is according to the div's previous position. The highlighted/indented div is a Sortable element. I understand this has probably something do with the CSS but am a noob at that!

Code;

```
<style>
      .ui-state-highlight {border: 4px solid #ffffa1;}
      .indent { margin: 0; padding-left: 10px; }
</style>
```

On Mouse Click;

```
if ($('#'+(parseInt(pushpin._text))).prop('class') == "indent ui-state-highlight" || $('#'+(parseInt(pushpin._text))).prop('class') == "ui-state-highlight indent"){  
    $('#'+(parseInt(pushpin._text))).removeClass("indent"); 
}
else{
    $('#'+(parseInt(pushpin._text))).addClass("indent");
}
```

On Mouseover

```
$('#'+(parseInt(pushpin._text))).addClass("ui-state-highlight")
```

Comment: You need to give the full code before we can debug. Define `pushpin`, `_text`, `prop()`, etc.

Comment: prop() is a jquery function, pushpin is a bing maps pushpin, the mouseover and mouse click events are for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `margin-left` instead of `padding-left`.

Padding is the space between the content and the border of the element. What you want is to "move" the element to the right.

Answer (score 0):

#### Just change the CSS to:

```
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-state-highlight.indent {border: 4px solid #ffffa1;}
.indent { margin: 0; padding-left: 10px; }
```

Should be a specificity issue.